# R - Error in arules and arulesViz packages

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-package

I am using the `arules` and `arulesViz` package in R to implement a set of association rules on my data. It worked fine till few days back. But now I am getting the below error whenever I load the R file where I used this package.

```
Loading required package: arules
Loading required package: Matrix
Attaching package: ‘arules’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
%in%, write
Error in length(obj) : Method length not implemented for class rules 
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘arules’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
Error in length(obj) : Method length not implemented for class rules 
Error in length(obj) : Method length not implemented for class rules 
Error in length(obj) : Method length not implemented for class rules
```

If I use the `plot()` function from `arulesViz` I face this below error:

```
Error in seq_along(x) : Method length not implemented for class rules
```

So tried to uninstall the package and reinstalled it. It worked only for the first time after reinstallation, it also threw the below error when I used for the first time after reinstallation.

```
Loading required package: arules
Loading required package: Matrix

Attaching package: ‘arules’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
%in%, write
```

But once I saved the file and loaded it back the old error messages repeated again.  I searched in Google but nothing close to this type of error is ever posted by anyone. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can it be, that after using everything "few days back" you updated your R from 2.x to the latest 3.13 version?

Comment: No I have been using the same version for past few months.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I got this same error and this SO page is the only Google result that comes up. This fixed it for me (but I don't know why...)

```
> detach("package:arules", unload=TRUE)
> library("arules", lib.loc="[wherever your R libraries go]")
```

Comment: Thanks, As of now I did not use the library()  in the code but used it in the console every time I run that code. A temporary fix.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I detached arules and arulesSequences and only loaded arulesSequences, then the error was gone. Something similar happened with shiny and shinyFiles. I think it might be a problem if a library loads another already loaded library and does not do it correctly.